# Update SQLite row with certain number

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3, better-sqlite3

I have a problem that I can't solve with better-sqlite3 on node.js
I have a table looking somewhat like this:

[image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiMMc.png)

How can I change each rows xp, that has a level of 3 to 100? So in this example it should change id's 1 and 4 xp value to 100.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How is this problem related to your DB choice? Please provide the code you've got and explain what you've tried so far to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic SQL Query, you're just needing to do a `WHERE` on all levels that equal 3.

```
UPDATE tableName
SET level = 100
WHERE level = 3
```

Looking at the `better-sqlite3` documentation, to do an `UPDATE` you simply need to call the function using `run()`

```
const stmt = db.prepare('UPDATE tableName SET level = ? WHERE level = ?');
const info = stmt.run(3, 100);
```